# Set the background color of a cell in a p:datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces `datatable` and I'm trying to set the `background-color` of cells as following :

```
<p:column sortBy="#{salle.couleur}">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{messages.Couleur}" />  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText  style="background-color:##{salle.couleur}" />  
                </p:column>
```

the value of `#{salle.couleur}` is something like this : `0909e8`, thats why use a `#` before the value.

But it doesn't work, and when I inspected the html page I can see that the cell has indeed a `background-color` :

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the inspected [`<span />`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) is empty, so there is nothing to color with a custom background. That is beacause you do not set the background color of the cell but of the cells content. I would recommend to set the background color on the cell itself via:

```xml
<p:column
    sortBy="#{salle.couleur}"
    style="#{empty salle ? '' : 'background-color: #'.concat(salle.couleur).concat(';')}"
>  
   ...
</p:column>
```

So even if the cells content is empty the cell itself will have a custom background color. The `empty salles` condition in the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) prevents the column header from getting colored also.